# What means "Brass tack secret"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could somebody explain to me what means "Brass tack secret" in the phrase?

> The column was regarded for revealing the brass-tacks secrets of research and showing home-based experimenters how to make original discoveries using only inexpensive materials

Comment: "important (practical) secrets"

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 'get down to brass tacks' means to focus on the essentials or basic facts of something. The 'brass-tack secrets' of research are the 'secrets' of how to conduct basic research.

[Get down to brass tacks (Grammarist)](https://grammarist.com/usage/get-down-to-brass-tacks/)

Comment: Note that, while _get down to brass tacks_ is a familiar idiom, it is not common to use the phrase _brass tacks_ in other constructions, and in particular I don't think I've seen it used attributively like this before. It is perfectly understandable, but not common. The iWeb corpus has 616 instances of _down to brass tacks_ out of 1140 _brass tacks_.